# Category products don't match database

Tags: sql, prestashop

I have a script that deletes specific entries from [prefix]_category_product ( => removes products from a category) using SQL.

Though the changes are successfully made in the database and in the Prestashop admin interface, they don't show on the front-end. Some products which have been removed from a category still appear in it.

I don't think it's a caching issue because emptying the Prestashop cache and the browser cache doesn't work, and they don't disappear after a few days/weeks. If I add and remove the product from the category manually using the admin interface it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the ps_product and ps_product_shop tables,
where the id_category_default value is stored.

Comment: I'm not, I made sure that the main category was set on something else, both in ps_product and ps_product_shop.

Comment: So it should be a cache issue... Try to empty smarty cache after db modification. If you have a database cache, make sure you are not reading stale data.